# Where can i get a copy of OS X Lion s/w?

Tags: macbook-pro

Where can I get a copy of the S/W Lion?
I want to "clean install OS X Lion" on my MBA 13" 2012, like it originally came.

AirRay

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing OS X Lion on an iMac](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63245/installing-os-x-lion-on-an-imac)

Comment: @killswitch The question here is about how to get Lion primarily, not about installing it.

Comment: From what I understand the Lion installer should still show up under your purchases in the Mac App Store. Can you check this? ( [see](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/07/25/how-to-re-download-lion-from-the-mac-app-store/) )

Answer (score 2):

If your Mac originally came with OS X Lion, is capable of doing internet recovery, and you have a WPA/WPA2 network, then booting using Internet Recovery will enable you to install OS X Lion. To boot into Internet Recovery, follow these steps:

1. Shutdown your Mac
2. Press the power button
3. Quickly release it and hold down Command-Option-R
4. Keep on holding it until a globe shows up, or a list of WiFi networks.
   For more assistance, visit https://www.apple.com/osx/recovery/

If that is not an option, you can purchase the OS X Lion download code from [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion). Upon recieving it, go to the Mac App Store and redeem the code. It will download like any other app. If you are installing it on a Mac running OS X 10.8 or later, you will need to create a bootable USB and wipe all your data, as the installer will not allow you to install 10.7 on a newer OS release. If you choose this way, be sure to make a copy of the Lion Installer and backup all of your files.